# Print query results when using format=alinged, instead of open them in EDITOR

Tags: postgresql, psql

If a do a select and only retrieve a few columns, the results are printed to the terminal, if I have more columns, and they do not fit in the terminal width, the query results are opened in the default editor (vim), but when I exit the editor the results are no longer visible.

I know I can user \x (but I have many rows, and for my it's seems worst ).
If I change the format to unaligned, html, latex or troff-ms even if the results are wider then the terminal width they are still printed.

When the resulted rows do not fit in the terminal height they are always opened in the default EDITOR, no mater what format I am using.

Q:
There is any posibility to use format=aligned and allways print the results instead of opening them in the default EDITOR, so I will not loose their visibility (something similar to what mysql-client does) ?

Thank you.

Comment: According to psql manpage but also common sense, `EDITOR` is used for `\e` and `\ef` commands, not for displaying results. Are you sure you're not confusing it with `PAGER`?

Comment: @DanielVérité I did not know that, but based on your comment I solved my problem with: \pset pager off , If you put it in an answer, I can vote up & accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query results are passed to the `PAGER` program when they don't fit in the screen, unless it's disabled with `\pset pager off`. `EDITOR` is used for input.

Some pagers restore the previous display when they quit, and it can be quite irritating when you need to use previous results in further queries.

I've found `PAGER="less -FX"` to be a good fit with `psql` since it allows scrolling in both directions and keeps the display intact when it quits.